# GRPC connection timeout for hyperledger fabric when sending proposal to the endorser

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

It is solved, please see this: [Connection timeout when installing chaincode using fabric-sdk-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792520/connection-timeout-when-installing-chaincode-using-fabric-sdk-go)

Dev ENV: Mac and Docker (3 CAs, 3 Orgs, 4 Peers)

Fabric SDK: fabric-sdk-go

Description: I use the sdk to install the chaincode but it errors out when sending proposal to the endorser. Seems that I cannot send the grpc request to the container. Things are working fine with the http request to the fabric CA containers.

ErrorMessage: 
unable to verify if cc is installed on grpcs://peer1-xxxx:7051. Got error: lscc.getinstalledchaincodes failed: SendProposal failed: Transaction processing for endorser [peer1-xxxx:7051]: Endorser Client Status Code: (2) CONNECTION_FAILED. Description: dialing connection timed out [peer1-xxxx:7051]

Comment: Assuming you are running the SDK on your host, what happens if you try `ping peer1-xxxx` on your host system?

Comment: @GariSingh 64 `bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.126 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.093 ms`  peer1-xxxx is mapped to 127.0.0.1 in the /etc/hosts file

Comment: How did you start your peers?  Are you using Docker Compose?  If so, can you post your compose file?  It's likely that your peers are actually listening on different ports as you cannot expose them all on the same port on the host

Comment: @GariSingh  See the gist please https://gist.github.com/RealDeanZhao/49afda54103c76956a47bec167a93559

Comment: So it looks like you should be able to connect to *peer1-xiaoyudian:7051* and *peer1-jinzun:7151* ?

Comment: @GariSingh I can only send the https request to ica-xiaoyudian:8054 but still cannot send grpcs request to peer1-xiaoyudian:7051 and peer2-xiaoyudian:8051.

Comment: Hmm .... can you post the output of *sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P*

Comment: com.docke 66486 dean   54u  IPv4 0xfd03d871caab9c63      0t0  TCP *:7051 (LISTEN)
com.docke 66486 dean   55u  IPv6 0xfd03d871cd9b525b      0t0  TCP [::1]:7051 (LISTEN)